# What's the best / easiest way to combine two mailboxes on Exchange 2007?

Tags: exchange-2007

I've found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) and [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201751%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx), but they both seem targeted toward much more complex cases than what I'm trying to do, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing some better approach.  Here's the scenario:

'Alice' has retired.  'Bob' has taken over Alice's position.  Bob was already with the organization in a different but related position, and so they already have their own Exchange account with mail, calendars, etc., that they need to keep.  I need to get all of Alice's old mail, calendar entries, etc., merged into Bob's existing stuff.  Ideally, I don't want to have all of Alice's stuff in a separate 'recovery' folder that Bob would have to switch back and forth between to look at older stuff; I want it all just merged into Bob's current Inbox / Calendar.

I'm assuming (read: hoping) that there's a better way to do this than fiddling with permissions and exporting to and then importing from a .pst.

Office version is 2007 for everybody that uses Exchange, if that helps.  Exchange is version 8.1.

What (preferably step-by-step - I'm new to Exchange) is the best way to do this?  I can't imagine this is an uncommon scenario, but my google-fu has failed me; there seems to be nothing on this subject that isn't geared towards far more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [export-mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964(EXCHG.80).aspx) cmdlet to export your mailbox to a .PST file, and then the [import-mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691363(EXCHG.80).aspx) one to import the data in the target mailbox.

You can also use export-mailbox to directly move data from one mailbox to another, but then you'll need to save them in a subfolder of the target mailbox.

Comment: +1 Just did this it's by far the quickest and easiest way imo

Comment: NB:  To import you'll need a 32-bit system with the 32-bit Exchange 2007 Management tools and Outlook.

Comment: +1 for the pure simplicity.